# ISP Network Control

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, fiber

I just got an FTTH connection and my ISP is a local operator who has taken a franchisee from a bigger ISP. He installed an ONU device to which I connect my Wireless Router.

Now, he gave me username and password which entered in router through PPPoe worked correctly, but when I connect my PC directly to the ONU device, and Dial up a connection through PPPoe in windows 10, it does not connect to the internet.

WHY?

And moreover, in the user manual of ONU device, its IP is given to be 192.168.1.1 but when I connect my PC to ONU, Command Prompt shows gateway to be 10.4.0.1.

When I enter this URL in browser no web console is shown, but the user manual shows it has a web page? How can I access the web page of ONU device?

Comment: The reason the gateway address is not 192.168.1.1 is simply due to the fact, your device has been configured differently.  I would not worry about the reason the gateway address is different.

Comment: Have you tried `http://10.4.0.1` or `http://192.168.1.1` or both? What is this ONU device and where did you find its manual?

Comment: try scanning the ONU to see what ports it is listening on. And it may be that the ONU is configured so that only your ISP can access the web page.

Comment: No, the gateway IP is not accessible. I got a box with ONU device with a manual and it says model:EUZ01GS. Also if I connect the fibre cable to ONU, only the web page of ISP login is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ONT devices are normally configured from the providers network. It's highly likely that it will **only** be configurable from the ISP facing interface.

On top of that, most ONT devices lock the MAC address of the WAN interface of the provided router to the ISP DHCP server.

You can try cloning the MAC address of the WAN interface from the provided router to your PC LAN adapter. My guess is that you will be able to dial in via ppoe with a cloned MAC, but it's doubtful you will be able to configure the ONT device this way.

I'm curious what you are trying to accomplish by doing this. The settings you are looking to see / configure usually have nothing to do with the client side connection, it has to do with the provider side connection, and how it interfaces with the ISP optical network.

This is intentional, if you did have access and messed around with the settings you would most likely break the connection to the ISP. The ISP would then have to dispatch to fix what you changed, because they would no longer be able to diagnose from the head-end.

Settings that a user needs to customize on their private network is in the **provided router**. If you don't like the customization options, or they do not fit your specific needs, buy a **compatible** router to replace it that does meet your specific network needs.

Best Regards,